# How to disable L3 programming layer

Tags: texlive, latex3, texlive-2019

I have a xmltex development project which runs on my office computer with texlive 2019, but not on my home computer with a (just now) installed texlive 2019. I noted that the recent texlive uses some LaTeX3 packages by default which the slightly older version does not.

The first few output lines of the newer texlive:

```
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.20 (TeX Live 2019/Debian) (preloaded format=latex)
 restricted \write18 enabled.
entering extended mode
(./main.tex
LaTeX2e <2020-02-02> patch level 2
L3 programming layer <2020-02-14> (./xmltex.tex
```

That last line does not appear in my slightly older work machine:

```
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.20 (TeX Live 2019) (preloaded format=latex)
 restricted \write18 enabled.
entering extended mode
(./main.tex
LaTeX2e <2018-12-01>
(./xmltex.tex
```

Somehow the l3backend-dvips.def seems to be incompatible with xmltex.tex, so the question is:

Is there a way to disable the "L3 programming layer" on the more recent texlive installation?

---

edit:

the actual error message that appears on my home machine is:

```
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3backend/l3backend-dvips.def

! LaTeX Error: Missing \begin{document}.

See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              

l.1 %
     %
? x
No pages of output.
```

The `l3backend-dvips` package is not attemtped to be included on the other, older, machine.

---

edit 2
I was asked for a MWE... Since the L3 programming layer-line and the automatic inclusion of the l3backend package, both of which i want to get rid of, are independend from any input, this will do:

main.tex:

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}
Test
\end{document}
```

latex run is

```
latex main
```

---

### edit3: (i removed the xmltex example because it was not really showing the original error but another one, which i noticed too late. Sorry.)

Again: my question is how i can prevent LaTeX from including any L3 packages in the most recent versions of texlive?

Comment: Can you also add a small example of a document producing the issue?

Comment: looks like your code changes the catcode of %, does it? That would fail whenever any file with comments is loaded. As @egreg says a small test file would really be needed to understand what is going on here.

Comment: Does the example code try to input `xmltex.tex`?

Comment: xmltex does that indeed, but i have no problems loading any other package that contains percent signs. the error is only thrown at l3backend after a couple of other packages are loaded, including babel...

Comment: @Lupino Please, be more specific about your issue. The example code you show compiles with no problem. But there is no loading of `xmltex`, nor of additional packages including `babel`.

Comment: My question is twice in the OP: How do I prevent LaTeX from loading `l3backend-<driver>.def`? (apart from downgrading texlive). Because in m MWE there is no line like `\input l3backend-dvips.def` either, but the file is loaded anyways.

Comment: @Lupino It's loaded automatically: you can't simply 'skip' it. We are trying to solve what _issue_ the loading is causing you.

Comment: Classic [XY problem](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2449/what-does-xy-problem-mean).  You assume that skipping the loading of L3 programming layer will solve your problem without even mentioning what your problem is.

Comment: @HenriMenke sorry, i thought after stripping down my original problem to that single addition in my logs, that i narrowed the culprit down to that single l3 programming layer.  And as long as LaTeX3 is not officially released, i thought, it could be deactivated somehow. You know, because it is still experimental....

Comment: @Lupino expl3 and the l3backend-driver are now part of the official latex. So you need to solve your problems with them.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer okay, that's a start, thanks.

Comment: I can't reproduce your problem. I get an error but before the l3backend driver is read at the main.xml. Did you adapt your xmltex.tex version somehow?

Comment: @UlrikeFischer is this addition documented somewhere?

Comment: @UlrikeFischer no, fresh copy from the texmf-dist path.

Comment: https://www.latex-project.org/news/latex2e-news/ltnews31.pdf. And check your example, as it is it fails for me also in older texlive. Or create a zip-file with all necessary files.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer could you put your comment into an answer, please? Because i really just wanted to know if (and how) the whole l3 thingy can be deactivated. That it can't, is my answer, and it means we have to take a look at all of our projects.

Comment: No, we want to know what is going on and if there is something we have to do. So provide a complete example that demonstrates the problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To answer your question about deactivation ... the L3 programming layer is part of the core LaTeX format since release 2019-10-01 and it can't be deactivated. At the moment it is there to speed up processing of packages written in expl3, e.g., xparse, fontspec, and many others, but going forward core parts of LaTeX will make direct use of it.

Deactivation is only possible by using a release prior to 2019-10 (even rollback via "latexrelease" will load).

It is therefore important to understand why get the issue which should not be the case.

Comment: After some discussion in the chat and seeing a real example: The OP uses a locally modified version of xmltex, and he can avoid the problem by loading the driver earlier with `\usepackage[driver=dvips]{expl3} ` (but as it looks as if the catcodes are wrong in begin document, it naturally can break in the future with other changes).

Comment: if the catcodes are wrong at begin document then all bets are off anyway % has to be acomment sign, nothing to do with L3 layer other than that is loading the driver code at this point. Other packages may load other stuff there so it can happen any time.

Comment: @FrankMittelbach as far as i understand the matter, the loading of l3backed happens at `\begin{document}`; xmltex changes the catcode for % also at `\begin{document}`  but earlier in order to allow the character as a valid text character in xml documents. Explicit `\includepackage` however are expanded prior to that switch therefore packages can use the % as comment character as usual. By moving expl3 up before `\begin{document}` the catcode switch happens afterwards and everything is fine. I just dont understand why latex loads l3backend that late in the first place?

Comment: @Lupino The L3 layer is loaded in the format only the backend is loaded at begin-document and it has to be because it can be altered in the preamble. Anyway, that is not the issue. The issue is that altering the catcode of % unconditionally is invalidating LaTeX. Any file could be loaded by LaTeX at that point or later and files can contain comments.

Comment: @FrankMittelbach well, comments in xml files don't use % as comment symbol, so the problem should only occur with packages and code in tex syntax that is hooked into the \AtBeginDocument hook, do I understand that correctly?

Comment: @Lupino If you have code that loads files or processes data in which % is not to be interpreted as a comment, you can do so, but you have to confine it to the part where you control all the processing an not generally. It is not confined to \AtBeginDocument that, say, config files could get loaded.